Why does a Niklas on Megaminx not do anything to the top layer?
When performing a Niklas
(U) R U' L' U R' U' L

on a Megaminx it does not permute three of the top corners. Everything stays in place, not even the orientation changes.
Instead the tutorials I found all use a Niklas with U2 (or U2') instead of U (or U') to permute three of the corners.
Why is that?

Because the Megaminx has 5-sided faces and the cube has 4-sided faces.
